# Generic function with multiple closures not working

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, closures

I would like to create a generic function that can aggregate an array into one type. I will be using a stupid but simple example to explain.

Let's say I got this code:

```
class Entity {
    var someElement: Int
}
```

Now I have written this function in an `Array extension`, so that I can use it on any array:

```
/**
 * An aggregation function. The first closure extracts the useful data in a new object, the second one aggregates two items of the same type in one.
 * 
 * The algorithm works from front to back
 *
 * @return the aggregated value or nil if the array is empty
 */
func aggregate<R>(translation: (T) -> R, aggregation: (R, R) -> R) -> R? {
    if count == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    if count == 1 {
        return translation(self.first!)
    }
    var calc = translation(self.first!)
    for item in 1..<count {
        calc = aggregation(calc, translation(self[item]))
    }
    return calc
}
```

And I'd like to use it like this:

```
let array: [Entity] = ... // something fills the array
array.aggregate(
    {
        item in 
        return item.someElement
    }, aggregation: {
        (item1, item2) in
        return item1 + item2
    }
)
```

But I get this crazy error: `Cannot convert the expression's type '((($T5) -> ($T5) -> $T4) -> (($T5) -> $T4) -> $T4, aggregation: (($T7, ($T7, $T8) -> ($T7, $T8) -> $T6) -> ($T7, ($T7, $T8) -> $T6) -> $T6, (($T7, $T8) -> ($T7, $T8) -> $T6, $T8) -> (($T7, $T8) -> $T6, $T8) -> $T6) -> (($T7, ($T7, $T8) -> $T6) -> $T6, (($T7, $T8) -> $T6, $T8) -> $T6) -> $T6)' to type 'R'`.

What in the world is going on? In Xcode, when I check the type of `item`, it is `<<error type>>`, so it doesn't even get there with it's compilation. Do I need to specify what R is in my function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Swift is having trouble inferring the type of the first closure.  If you update your call to aggregate to explicitly give the types:

```
array.aggregate(
    {
        (item: Entity)->Int in
        return item.someElement
    }, aggregation: {
        (item1, item2) in
        return item1 + item2
    }
)
```

it compiles/runs ok.

Interestingly, if you don't use the explicit returns, the inference works OK:

```
array.aggregate(
    {
        item in
         item.someElement
    }, aggregation: {
        (item1, item2) in
        return item1 + item2
})
```

(`array.aggregate({ $0.someElement},+)` also works fine)

P.S. if you're interested in an alternative, you could rewrite `aggregate` as follows:

```
extension Array {
    func aggregate<R>(translation: T -> R, aggregation: (R, R) -> R) -> R? {

        return self.first.map { fst in
            dropFirst(self).reduce(translation(fst)) { aggregation($0, translation($1)) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking this might be the problem. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: To your edit: well I guess that's just the beta speaking, I hope this will be fixed in a next version. I'll file a bugreport on that.

Comment: Also, using the map function is also a good idea, I'll test the two different methods for speed and use the one that's fastest.

Comment: I have run a test up to 10K elements, in a `for` loop where each time an element is added. The results got printed in a csv format and is available [here](http://pastebin.com/WRQkn8eU) (data in nanoseconds). I have created [this graph](https://i.imgur.com/LT7Mof0.png). Man, creating that graph took ages on my early 2011 base MBP. I guess it's time for an upgrade. TL;DR: your mapreduce way is faster by about factor 2 or 3.